# FilteredPaste.js working with textarea

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am working with jQuery plugin called [FilteredPaste.js](http://willemmulder.github.io/FilteredPaste.js/) that removes all HTML elements when copy and pasted to a input. I want to apply it to textarea element but it does not seems to work. Nothing gets pasted. The example uses `contenteditable` but I need to use `textarea` instead. Or any alternative plugin suggestion is welcome.

Here is what I have so far.

```
  jQuery(document).ready(

    function() {

        $("#content").filteredPaste({
            "filters" : ["default"]
        }); 

    }
  );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9M3vh/

Comment: As far as I can tell, none of their demos use textareas. They all use `<div contenteditable="true">`

Comment: Yes. I know they use  want to use contenteditable but I need to use textarea instead.

Comment: The fact that they've only used demos with a contenteditable may mean that using a textarea will not work...